# Why can a variable be expressed as a function of $\operatorname{sech}$?

Tags: calculus

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2m+1)(2n+1)((2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)} = \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1- \operatorname{sech} (\frac{\pi}{2} (2m+1))}{(2m+1)^3} 
$$

I know
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} = \frac{\pi}{4},
$$but I'm wondering how the part with the $n$ and $m$ is represented in $\operatorname{sech}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

$$S(m)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2m+1)(2n+1)((2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)}$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2m+1)(2n+1)((2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)}$$
A standart way of evaluation of such sum is to consider the integral in the complex plane along a big circle (radius $R\to\infty$)
$$I=\frac1{2(2m+1)}\oint_{C_R} \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac{dz}{(2z+1)((2m+1)^2+(2z+1)^2)}\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,R\to\infty$$
On the other hand,
$$I=2\pi i\frac1{2(2m+1)}\sum\operatorname{Res}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(2z+1)((2m+1)^2+(2z+1)^2)}$$
i.e. the sum of all residues inside the contour.

We have only simple poles inside the contour; the residues at $z=0;\pm1;\pm2...$ give the desired sum; we also have simple poles at $z=-\frac12$ and $z=-\frac12\pm\frac{i(2m+1)}2$:
$$\frac1{2(2m+1)}\underset{z=0;\pm1;\pm2...}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(2z+1)((2m+1)^2+(2z+1)^2)}$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2m+1)(2n+1)((2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)}=S(m)$$
Hence,
$$S(m)=-\frac1{2(2m+1)}\underset{{\binom{z=-\frac12}{z=-\frac12\pm\frac{i(2m+1)}2}}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(2z+1)((2m+1)^2+(2z+1)^2)}$$
$$=-\frac1{16(2m+1)}\underset{{\binom{z=-\frac12}{z=-\frac12\pm\frac{i(2m+1)}2}}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(z+\frac12)(z+\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)(z+\frac12-i\frac{2m+1}2)}$$
The residues evaluation is straightforward, for example
$$-\frac1{16(2m+1)}\underset{z=-\frac12}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(z+\frac12)(z+\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)(z+\frac12-i\frac{2m+1}2)}$$
$$=-\frac1{16(2m+1)}\frac{\pi}{\sin(-\frac\pi2)}\frac1{(\frac12-\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)(\frac12-\frac12-i\frac{2m+1}2)}$$
$$=\frac\pi4\frac1{(2m+1)^3}$$
$$-\frac1{16(2m+1)}\underset{z=-\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}\frac1{(z+\frac12)(z+\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)(z+\frac12-i\frac{2m+1}2)}$$
$$-\frac1{16(2m+1)}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi (-\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)}\frac1{(-\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2+\frac12)(-\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2+\frac12+i\frac{2m+1}2)}$$
$$=-\frac\pi 8\frac1{(2m+1)^3\cosh\frac{2m+1}2}$$
The residue at $z=-\frac12-i\frac{2m+1}2$ is being evaluated in the same way.

What all together gives the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'm getting the gist of it, but could you elaborate a bit more? especially what it mean sigma (Res)?

Comment: @Hyeonsoo $\sum_{\text{Res}}$ simply just means the sum of all [residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis))

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I can't understand all what you solve, but i will try to understand!

Comment: Thank you very much. I've solved the problem, but I'm wondering if you could solve one last one...? Latex: 
\prod_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 p+1)^{2}}{(2 p+1)^{2}+(2 m+1)^{2}}
This is last question, but what you explain me is understandable, this is..I have no idea.. 

I know you're busy, but I was wondering if you had a few minutes to spare. T.T

Comment: The answer is $\frac1{\cosh\frac\pi2(2m+1)}$ Why don't you put your problem in the open space - together with your try - to get more help and (probably) even different solutions?

Comment: I signed up and posted a post about this same problem, but because it was my first time, I posted it as a picture without converting the expressions to Latex code, and got downvotes, so I couldn't post it.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Hello, I thought I understood the first time, but can I ask a question again?
Why does pi/sin(pi*z) stick when you assume a radius of infinity and integrate on a large circle below it? 
Because if I didn't have this term, when I tried to add back the residues for residue z=-1/2, -1/2 +- i(2m+1)/2, I ended up with zero. 
Can anyone tell me why pi/sin(pi*z) has to happen?

Comment: $\frac\pi{\sin\pi z}$ has simple poles at $z=0,\pm1, \pm2, ... (z=k) $ with the residue $(-1)^k$. Integrating along a big circle with the function $f(z)$, these poles give $2\pi i\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^kf(k)$

Comment: @Svyatoslav
Hello, I'm working on the next course, and I've been studying a lot of other things so I can understand your process. 

However, I keep getting stuck on the next part of the course, and I'm wondering if you can help me with that. I've left a new question. 

I hope you can help me, thank you.